# Using Sendgrid's SSO Teammate Personas, Can "create" and "send" be separated?

Tags: email, single-sign-on, sendgrid, persona, teammate

I have read [the sendgrid teammate permissions](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/teammate-permissions#persona-scopes) page that talks about `personas` that can be assigned to SSO users.

I'm not finding an answer to this simple goal. We desire to have one group of "email creators" and one group that can "authorize the sending of an email".

This is not in the context of transactional emails, this is in the context of campaign emails where an email is created in a wysiwyg editor and then once ready for sending, the creator would not be able to send the email, the email would have to be sent by a member of the "authorized to send" group. *The creator group should be able to assign a distribution list.*

**Can SSO Teammate Permissions be setup (with or without Personas) to accomplish a two group setup where there are email content creators and email content approvers?**